# Sitecore Authentication Persistence over Subdomains

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, sitecore, sitecore7, subdomain

I am trying to configure my website so that the user can stay logged in even if he navigates to a different subdomain (seperate content trees in sitecore).

Just to be crystal clear, if I have the following domains:

> site.com
>   ex1.site.com
>   ex2.site.com

and so on, I want the user to remain logged in when navigating between them. I am using the `Sitecore AuthenticationManager`.

Could anyone please help me with this one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As Sitecore uses the ASP.NET Membership Provider for Authentication and Authorization of users and roles the following should work:

http://blog.nick.josevski.com/2013/06/12/cross-subdomain-asp-net-forms-authentication-for-local-developement/